# Pandas: How to eliminate cell comments (the "Insert Comment" variety)

Tags: python, pandas, comments

I have a multi-sheet spreadsheet (ODS) which has explanatory comments on the header row cells; the type that pop-up when the mouse hovers over a cell..

The header row is: `'field_name', 'alt_names', 'type'`  where I used right-click + Insert Comment on the first cell and entered "Inserted comment"

When reading the sheet, I get:

```
['', 'FirstName']
['LastName2023-11-30T13:00:00Inserted']
['commentfield_name', 'alt_names', 'type']
```

Note the 3rd line: 'commentfield_name' is the last word in the "comment" and the cell content with no delimiter separating the parts.

What I want:

```
['field_name', 'alt_names', 'type']
```

I've tried "comment='#'; but that only works on cell *content*, not cell *comments*; and adding '#' at the start of a cell comment kills all remaining data from the sheet.

```py
NL = '\n'
data = pd.read_excel('file.ods',engine='odf',sheet_name='x',skiprows=0).to_csv().split({NL})
```

More specifically; I need a general solution where the caption is clearly identifiable. Upon reflection, I could look for a termination character (i.e., period)...  However, that risks the possibility that the source spreadsheet does not contain one.

Looking at the XML:

```xml
<table:table-cell ...>
 <office:annotation ...>
  <dc:creator>FirstName LastName</dc:creator>
   <dc:date>2023-11-30T17:12:00</dc:date>
    <text:p>Column name to use in all cases.</text:p>
 </office:annotation>
<text:p>field_name</text:p>
```

It seems to me pandas likely has this covered; but I haven't found the secret sauce yet...  XML clearly identifies the comment (annotation) with **creator** and **date**, so I'm surprised pandas just concatenates the annotation and the cell's text, while splitting the annotation unnecessarily; the above XML results in:

```
['', 'FirstName']
['LastName2023-11-30T17:12:00Column']
['name']
['to']
['use']
['in']
['all']
['cases.field_name', '"FirstName']
```

while it would make more sense to return:

```
['', 'FirstName LastName','2023-11-30T17:12:00','Column name to use in all cases.'],['field_name']
```

or better yet, simply: `['field_name','alt_name','type']` if there's an option to request the sheet contents without *annotations* -- which is what I'm really trying to find...

Note that in this example, I showed a single annotation; the real source has annotations on most of the cells in the header row.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you know what the last row is and where the comment lays within that (which is index 0 of the list), all you would have to do is to strip it out.

I do it with slicing like this:

```
last_row = ['commentfield_name', 'alt_names', 'type']
x = [last_row[0][7:], last_row[1], last_row[2]]
print(x)
```

which returns this:

```
['field_name', 'alt_names', 'type']
```

or you could do this:

```
last_row = ['commentfield_name', 'alt_names', 'type']
last_row[0] = last_row[0][7:]
```

which would give the same.